# Cannot open file dialog box present inside pop up screen using jQuery/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to open the file dialog using jQuery but it's not opening inside the pop-up screen. If I am putting it outside the `pop-up` div it's working fine. I am providing my code below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).on('click', '.brevent', function(e){
          var file = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.file');
          file.trigger('click');
          e.stopImmediatePropagation();
          e.preventDefault();
          console.log('hello');
    });
    $(document).on('change', '.file', function(){
          $(this).parent().find('.form-control').val($(this).val().replace(/C:\\fakepath\\/i, ''));
    });
})
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#addeventdiv").on('click', function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $(".daterangepicker").on('click', function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $("#addeventclose").click(function() {
        $("#addeventdiv").fadeToggle(400);
    });
    $("#addevent").on('click', function(e) {
        $("#addeventdiv").fadeToggle(400);
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $("body").on('click', function(e) {
        if (e.target.className == "#addeventdiv") {
        } else {
            $('#addeventdiv').css("display", "none");
        }
    });
});
```

[Here is my full plunkr code](https://plnkr.co/edit/4oV7AAPAx9asvUXokoBh?p=preview). I have one `Add event` button. When user will click on this button the form will display and there user has to click on `Attachment` button which is not working as per expected.

Comment: Why not click `<>` and post the code here?

Comment: I have created the `plunkr` to see the exact issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your delegation fails. Likely because the dialog blocks the document click.

Just add this to any of the loads since the button click does not need to be delegated since it exists in the code at load time

```
$('.brevent').on("click", function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var file = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.file');
      file.trigger('click');
      e.stopImmediatePropagation();
      console.log('hello');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your handler for all clicks in #addeventdiv gets the event first and stops propagation.  I think https://plnkr.co/edit/FWRAKwlUeIRarY6bZl9n?p=preview will work as you expect:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".daterangepicker").on('click', function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $("#addeventclose").click(function() {
        $("#addeventdiv").fadeToggle(400);
    });
    $("#addevent").on('click', function(e) {
        $("#addeventdiv").fadeToggle(400);
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $("#addeventclose").on('click', function(e) {
      $('#addeventdiv').css("display", "none");
    });
    $("body").on('click', function(e) {
      if (!$(e.target).parent("#addeventdiv").length) {
        $('#addeventdiv').css("display", "none");
      }
    });
});
```

Just as a stylistic nitpick, you only need one document ready handler per file

Comment: I have also another requirement that click on body the pop screen will not display. Which is not happening in your case.

Comment: @satya no, just the SO answer